# InfoWpis System does not let my salary

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using infowpis prac v 1-192VB.
I've filled in all entries for each day but the system doesn't let my sallary

Has anyone had the same problem?

Maybe I need to check last year's easter holidays if I supplied system with proper entries
(0h / day)?

Please guys let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Hi, not sure what your issue is. You say "the system doesn't let my sallary", but you provide no verb for what you want the salary to do, or be processed by.

Answer (score 0):

First, see if the all the entries are correct. History shows that you also could missclicked and deleted some entries from the database.
Finally you can check if the PB() has the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the system as of living organism. It thinks, it feels, it interacts with the environment, it evolves. You had to hurt it someday and it remembers your fault against it.
That's why system won't let!
Just be a better man! Maybe you will be forgiven then and system start letting again.